# How do I return values of one class method to other method of the same class

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, self

Below is my class and I want to return the values of n and d in function add() to function simplify() so as to return the fraction after computing GCD, how can I do this? Also, I can't just call the add function in simplify because I will then have to add functions for all the other computations
Below is the code:

```
class Fraction:
    def __init__(self, num, denom) -> None:  
    
        self.num = num 
        self.denom = denom 
        if self.denom == 0:
            raise ZeroDivisionError("cannot divide by zero")

    def __add__(self, other: "Fraction") -> "Fraction": 

        n: int = self.num * other.denom + self.denom * other.num
        d: int = self.denom * other.denom

    def simplify(self) -> "Fraction":

        n1: Fraction = abs(self.num)
        n2: Fraction= abs(self.denom)
        gcd: int = 1
        k:int = 1
        while k <= n1 and k <= n2:
            if n1 % k == 0 and n2 % k == 0:
                gcd = k
            k += 1
       a:int = self.num / gcd
       b:int = self.denom / gcd
       new = Fraction(a,b)
       return new
```

Comment: You can do it like you did to pass `self.num` and `self.denom` to function simplify(). Just use `self.n` and `self.d`.

Comment: I don't think that works, they are not part of the class Fraction but variables in one of the method. I tried it but throws error.